# How to see the number of function calls and if possible the function names that are in the stack real-time

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, memory, stack

Is there a way in real-time to see the number of function calls that are in the stack before or regardless of whether the stack size might be exceeded? Could it be shown like this:

```
console.log("Function: " + funcName + ", nbr of calls in the stack: " + funcCount);
// Function: foo, 22
// Function: bar, 300
// etc...
```

Functions are called like this:

```
var mod = function () { 
   var obj = {
        foo: (fn) => "My name is: " + fn, 
        bar: (fn) => "My name is: " + fn
    };
    console.log(((fn) => obj[fn](fn))("foo"));
    console.log(((fn) => obj[fn](fn))("bar"));
}; 
mod();
// My name is: foo
// My name is: bar
```

So the function when running knows its name since it's passed in.

Comment: Why do you need this? Seems like [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: To manage async vs non-async calls.  Too many non-async calls creates a problem.  Inserting more async calls or longer delays will give the stack time to clear.  Knowing how many calls are pending helps figure this out.